# Making an ANN for Polynomial Regression

Tags: python, neural-network, linear-regression

I have an assignment to build an ANN for regression problems using Python from scratch without using any ML library. You might have guessed I am a true beginner at this and the process is a little confusing so I would really appreciate some help in answering the few questions that I have.

This is the basic training algorithm that I understand for training an ANN:

- Forward prop for prediction
- Backward prop to calculate errors
- Calculate deltas for each weight using the errors
- Accumulate deltas over a dataset iteration and calculate the partial gradient for each weight
- Optimize weights using gradient descent

I hope the steps make sense and are okay. Here are a few questions that I have:

1. What activation function should I use? Sigmoid is probably not the answer.
2. Should an activation function be used on the single output node?
3. The formula to calculate errors for hidden layers in back-prop is `` δ(l) = Transpose[ϴ(l)] x δ(l+1) .* g`[z(l)] `` where `l` is the layer number and `` g`[z(l)] `` I believe is the derivative of the activation function usually taken as `a(l) .* (1 - a(l))`. Will this change as we use an activation function other than sigmoid?
4. Any errors I made or any important tip?

Apologies if the questions are very basic. I am a raw beginner at this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone stumbles upon this with any of the same queries, here are the answers:

1 - Sigmoid should work but it restricts the output between 0 and 1 and since this was a regression problem, you could design your problem to get a normalized output and scale it to the right number. Or just use ReLU.

2 - Yes. The type of activation on the output node changes the type of output you get.

3 - Of course it will. The derivative of the activation gradient is multiplied with the backpropagating global gradient to give the local gradient. Changing the activation function will change the derivative too.

4 - Maybe try to understand the Math behind backpropagation. It's basic chain rule and once you get it, you won't get confused like this.